# Exchange transport rule to silently ignore messages sent to a bogus address?

Tags: exchange-2010

Is it possible to configure a transport rule such that when an email sent to a specific bogus address, e.g.

blackhole@mycompany.com

it will be silently accepted without generating an "undeliverable" reply?  I tried a "delete the message without notifying anyone" rule, but it still generates the NDR.

We have no need for the messages at all, in fact it's preferred that they are just dropped, so we don't have to maintain a mailbox full of useless messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were able to accomplish this by simply adding blackhole@mycompany.com as an alias for some other account with a mailbox.  This enabled the transport rule to fire and the message to be dropped without an NDR, like we wanted.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking to do is create a catchall address.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb691132(v=exchg.141).aspx

Comment: thanks for the answer.  I'd prefer just to drop the messages because they are not needed.  I've updated my question.